# sum of count(*) for all rows in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, rdbms

I'm stuck with `sum()` query where I want the sum of `count(*)` values in all rows with `group by`.

Here is the query:

```
select
    u.user_type as user,
    u.count,
    sum(u.count)
FROM
(
select 
    DISTINCT
    user_type,
    count(*) as count
FROM
    users
where
    (user_type = "driver" OR user_type = "passenger")
GROUP BY
    user_type
) u;
```

Current Output:

```
----------------------------------
|  user     |  count     |  sum  |
----------------------------------
| driver    | 58         |  90   |
----------------------------------
```

Expected Output:

```
----------------------------------
|  user     |  count     |  sum  |
----------------------------------
| driver    | 58         |  90   |
| passenger | 32         |  90   |
----------------------------------
```

If I remove `sum(u.count)` from query then output is looks like:

```
--------------------------
|  user     |  count     |
--------------------------
| driver    | 58         |
| passenger | 32         |
--------------------------
```

Comment: Instead of `) u;` replacing `) u GROUP BY u.user_type, u.count` is helpful?

Comment: No, It's not. When I try to add this, it returns the same value as a count column.

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT(user_type) as diff, COUNT(user_type) total from users where (user_type = "driver" OR user_type = "passenger") group by user_type`

should work.

Comment: @bencagri It returns the same output when I remove `sum()` to form the parent query.

Comment: @philipxy I was gone through Google but didn't get a solution for this particular problem. And I believe that all of here are more specialist in their field then google. That's why I came here and set the bounty and reduce mine points. I know "how to ask". If you have a specific answer then please mention it. I think this is the best way to help instead of putting the comments which held miss focus on the main point.

Comment: I put it in the comments tell you about researching, not just to get you an answer for this question. Read the google search help. Google with 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags & many variants. Although also without because there are many other sources for such obvious beginner queries. (Re DBs also search at 'site:dba.stackexchange.com'). The SE search facility is poor.  Sometimes it's just not worth searching for duplicates I don't already have. Also I can't vote to close this as duplicate while it has a bonus.

Comment: PS Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need a subquery:

```
   SELECT user_type, 
          Count(*) AS count,
          (SELECT COUNT(*) 
           FROM users 
           WHERE user_type IN ("driver","passenger" )) as sum  
   FROM   users 
   WHERE  user_type IN ("driver","passenger" ) 
   GROUP  BY user_type ;
```

Note you dont need `distinct` here.

OR

```
   SELECT user_type, 
          Count(*) AS count,
          c.sum
   FROM   users 
   CROSS JOIN ( 
           SELECT COUNT(*) as sum
           FROM users 
           WHERE user_type IN ("driver","passenger" )
         ) as c

   WHERE  user_type IN ("driver","passenger" ) 
   GROUP  BY user_type ;
```

Comment: i dont think you should hard code user types? like he can have dynamic multiple user types

Comment: @mayur did you check my query?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Yes, I've checked it. Nice try. From this query, and I Got the sum too but it's an inconvenient way to do so. Coz, it queries every time for each row.

Comment: I give another version. But no much more you can do. You are trying to count two different things so you need join two different queries

Comment: @Mayur, I'm not sure it will query the 'sum' every time for each row, the engine should be clever enough to realise it only needs to run it once in the first case.. and it will only run it once to produce the table `c` before the JOIN in the second case

Comment: The first subquery (subselect) is not "correlated" and MySQL will execute it only once.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I've checked both types and got the output as I neede. Though It is not an appropriate way to do so. But I think That's enough efforts You all guys done for me. 
Thanks.

Comment: what you mean isnt apropiated?

Answer (score 10):

You can use [`WITH ROLLUP` modifier](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html):

```
select coalesce(user_type, 'total') as user, count(*) as count
from users
where user_type in ('driver', 'passenger')
group by user_type with rollup
```

This will return the same information but in a different format:

```
user      | count
----------|------
driver    |    32
passenger |    58
total     |    90
```

[db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dRwCEpokAmaatgjBy7ZaB6/0)

In MySQL 8 you can use `COUNT()` as [window function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-usage.html):

```
select distinct
  user_type,
  count(*) over (partition by user_type) as count,
  count(*) over () as sum
from users
where user_type in ('driver', 'passenger');
```

Result:

```
user_type | count | sum
----------|-------|----
driver    |    32 |  90
passenger |    58 |  90
```

[db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/we7iG9Z3Chug3NhoAMjkVw/0)

or use [CTE (Common Table Expressions)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html):

```
with cte as (
  select user_type, count(*) as count
  from users
  where user_type in ('driver', 'passenger')
  group by user_type
)
select user_type, count, (select sum(count) from cte) as sum
from cte
```

[db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xBtRX1BrqBtGqe8y9kGkPm/0)

Answer (score 7):

I would be tempted to ask; **Are you sure you need this at the DB level?**

Unless you are working purely in the database layer, any processing of these results will be built into an application layer and will presumably require some form of looping through the results

It could be easier, simpler, and more readable to run

```
  SELECT user_type,
         COUNT(*) AS count
    FROM users
   WHERE user_type IN ("driver", "passenger")
GROUP BY user_type
```

.. and simply add up the total count in the application layer

As pointed out by Juan in another answer, the DISTINCT is redundant as the GROUP BY ensures that each resultant row is different

Like Juan, I also prefer an IN here, rather than OR condition, for the user_type as I find it more readable. It also reduces the likelihood of confusion if combining further AND conditions in the future

As an aside, I would consider moving the names of the user types, "driver" and "passenger" into a separate user_types table and referencing them by an ID column from your users table

**N.B.** If you absolutely do need this at the DB level, I would advocate using one of Paul's excellent options, or the CROSS JOIN approach proffered by Tom Mac, and by Juan as his second suggested solution

Answer (score 6):

Try this. Inline view gets the overall total :

```
SELECT a.user_type, 
       count(*) AS count,
       b.sum  
FROM   users a
JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) as sum 
      FROM users 
      WHERE user_type IN ("driver","passenger" )
     ) b ON TRUE
WHERE  a.user_type IN ("driver","passenger" ) 
GROUP  BY a.user_type;
```

Comment: if you do group by at the end, you dont get the whole sum

Comment: exactly @JuanCarlosOropeza

Comment: ah yes. Quite right. Misunderstood the original question. Edited.

Answer (score 6):

You could simply combine `SUM() OVER()` with `COUNT(*)`:

```
SELECT user_type, COUNT(*) AS cnt, SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER() AS total
FROM  users WHERE user_type IN ('driver', 'passenger') GROUP BY user_type;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b00f793dbf0e0dbfe770cadc5774c16b)**

---

Output:

```
+------------+------+-------+
| user_type  | cnt  | total |
+------------+------+-------+
| passenger  |  58  |    90 |
| driver     |  32  |    90 |
+------------+------+-------+
```

Answer (score 3):

Add a `group by` clause at the end for `user-type`, e.g:

```
select
    u.user_type as user,
    u.count,
    sum(u.count)
FROM
(
select 
    DISTINCT
    user_type,
    count(*) as count
FROM
    users
where
    (user_type = "driver" OR user_type = "passenger")
GROUP BY
    user_type
) u GROUP BY u.user_type;
```

Comment: Above query will give me the output same like count.

Answer (score 2):

**Tom Mac Explain Properly Your answer. Here is the another way you can do that.
I check the query performance and not found any difference within 1000 records**

```
   select user_type,Countuser,(SELECT COUNT(*) 
   FROM users 
   WHERE user_type IN ('driver','passenger ') )as sum from (
   select user_type,count(*) as Countuser from users a
   where a.user_type='driver'
   group by a.user_type
   union
   select user_type,count(*) as Countuser from users b
   where b.user_type='passenger'
   group by b.user_type
   )c
   group by user_type,Countuser
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
WITH SUB_Q AS (
  SELECT USER_TYPE, COUNT (*) AS CNT
  FROM USERS
  WHERE USER_TYPE = "passenger" OR USER_TYPE = "driver"
  GROUP BY USER_TYPE
), 
SUB_Q2 AS (
  SELECT SUM(CNT) AS SUM_OF_COUNT
  FROM SUB_Q
)
SELECT A.USER_TYPE, A.CNT AS COUNT, SUB_Q2 AS SUM
FROM SUB_Q JOIN SUB_Q2 ON (TRUE);
```

I used postgresql dialect but you can easily change to a subquery.

Answer (score 0):

```
select
    u.user_type as user,
    u.count,
    sum(u.count)
FROM users group by user
```